# Will the new iPad Mini update to iOS8 when activated the first time?

Tags: ipad, software-update, ios

My boyfriend bought me an iPad Mini last September and until now it is on the box he didn't open it because he wanted me to open it on my own, but the thing is the iPad will arrived here in the Philippines on December. My question is when i open or turn on the ipad is it updated to ios 8 right away or I will be the one to update it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update it yourself. The iPad most likely has iOS 7 on it, and will only update itself once you have confirmed that you would like it to be updated.